# prerender.io aws elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, seo, prerender

I'm trying to get prerender.io to work on AWS Elastic Beanstalk(eb) micro instance with an Angular application on a different instance. I am able to get the Angular app and prerender server to work locally but I'm getting the following error when I deploy to eb.

> ERROR: Invalid Parameter Value: '0.10.10' for parameter: NodeVersion -
>   Value is not one of the allowed values: [0.8.26, 0.8.28, 0.10.21,
>   0.10.26, 0.10.31, 0.12.0]

I tried updating the prerender.config directly to set NodeVersion to 0.10.21 but that didn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: Have you tried installing a required nodejs version as the error states?
`node --version` (and change config  back to as it was)

Comment: Todd from prerender got back to me on github
https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/180

Basically I needed to choose a different AMI during install and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change node version in .ebextensions/prerender.config